# How to revert to last save on Xbox 360 from PC

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I deleted the game updates all the way to the first tutorial to see if duplicating diamond blocks was possible. When I loaded the world, I spawned in water, but not where I last was. There was just one island, not the world that was supposed to be there. It asked me to overwrite it and save and accidentally said yes.

Can I hook up my Xbox to my PC and go into my files to my last save?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that this happened:

Let's say the original save is called A.  You loaded A on an older version, which translated A into B.  Saving caused the save file known as A to become B.  You have B.

I don't see how you can change B to A based on the information provided.

Firstly, you ran an older build of the game on what appears to be a save created on a later version.  This is very likely why the map didn't appear as you had expected.

Secondly, you saved over your map.  Without a backup you have appeared to have lost your world.

Your only real options are to:

1. Hope you had a backup of the save (you can do this by copying the save file to the cloud storage or a USB drive, and then copying back across the file when you want to restore)
2. Still love the game enough to recreate your world
3. Hope that the saved world has enough of the original world to continue (for example, running on an older version maybe only shifted you to a new place so you could in theory find your creations after some exploring)

Comment: If I hook up my xbox to pc will I see mine craft files to delete the overwritten save on?

Comment: @DonuTJustin - Yes, you can use a PC but will need save editor tools (Horizon, Modio etc). You can use a USB stick to transfer the saves between the PC and the Xbox (will need the same tools to read the Xbox-formatted USB stick).

Comment: So your saying I can't plug in an Ethernet cable to the Xbox to the pc to delete a save on my world? What will those editor tools allow me to do?

Comment: Also, after it ask to overwrite the world and save, I clicked yes than after that I exited without saving. Another thing is that you know how mine craft on Xbox saves a little screen shot of where u were after u save an exit the world. Well It saved it when I was in my house.  So if that save than I'm thinking that I can reload it to that save.